# Ambiguous column name when using alias in join

Tags: sql, questdb

Why does this query produce an "Ambiguous column name" error when I include the "as time" alias? If I remove "as time" or "SAMPLE BY 1d", it goes away.

```
SELECT a.ts as time, sum(a.to_grid), sum(a.from_grid), sum(b.hourly_production)
FROM 'eloverblik' as a, 'ap_systems' as b
WHERE a.ts = b.ts
SAMPLE BY 1d;
```

Edit: The schemas are:

```
ap_systems
  ts timestamp
  hourly_production double

eloverblik
  ts timestamp
  to_grid double
  from_grid double
```

Edit2:
The following query using another alias and join syntax have the same issue

```
SELECT e.ts as timecol, sum(e.to_grid), sum(e.from_grid), sum(a.hourly_production)
FROM 'eloverblik' as e INNER JOIN 'ap_systems' as a ON
 (e.ts = a.ts)
SAMPLE BY 1d;
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of the two tables "*eloverblik*" and "*ap_systems*"?

Comment: `time` migth be a reserved keyword. Try something like `time_`

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) and [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I doesn't seem to matter what the alias is. I tried other names, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

`time` is a reserved keyword, use another name such as `timestamp`.
Rename the aliases to something more descriptive, but short.
Use `JOIN` syntax.
These solutions were essentially recommended in the comments by *umadik* and *Honeybadger*.

```
SELECT e.ts as timestamp, sum(e.to_grid) as sum_to_grid, sum(e.from_grid) as sum_from_grid, sum(a.hourly_production) as sum_hourly_production
FROM 'eloverblik' as e INNER JOIN 'ap_systems' as a ON
     (e.ts = a.ts)
SAMPLE BY 1d;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change the alias, but it didn't matter. Also tried with the `JOIN` syntax, but still same issue.

Comment: Maybe it needs to alias the `sum` columns? Updated the answer.